# Software for sensor manipulation

Tags: wifi

I am searching for open source software for wireless sensors’ management in a wireless sensor network environment. More specifically, I have some 802.11-based temperature sensors which are connected with a pc using a 802.11 router. I need to put configurable open source software into the pc to manipulate the information that comes from the sensors. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Zenoss Core Community](http://community.zenoss.org/) edition to accomplish the task you mentioned. It allows you to monitor several temperature sensors, storing the information in circular databases. Once deployed, you don't need to perform too much housekeeping.

If your sensors implements SNMP (Simple Network Managment Protocol) all you need is to enable the protocol according to manufacturer specs and let zenoss to discover your devices.

You can create customized reports and trigger events based on your custom configuration (eg, send an email when temperature is over certain level).

Finally, if the monitoring info is retrieved using a different method other than SNMP,  you can code custom scripts with Python, so that you help to zenoss to retrieve the info needed. Dig into the forums. Chances are the script is already available for your sensor.